# Display treeView

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, spring, spring-mvc

this is my controller method ,where i set treeView attribute,
Now i want to display that in jsp as treeview

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/main.html", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView showMainMenu(Model model, HttpServletRequest request){

TreeViewMenuDAO tvmDao=new TreeViewMenuDAO();
    List<TreeView> list=new ArrayList<TreeView>();
    List<Object> treeView=tvmDao.getDetailsList("1","92");

    Object[] arr = new Object[5];
    for(int j=0;j<treeView.size();j++)
    {
        arr = (Object[])treeView.get(j);
        TreeView treeObj =new TreeView();
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {  
            switch(i){
            case 0:treeObj.setLevel((BigDecimal)arr[i]);break;
            case 1:treeObj.setProgName((String)arr[i]);break;
            case 2:treeObj.setProgCd((BigDecimal)arr[i]);break;
            case 3:treeObj.setParentCd((BigDecimal)arr[i]);break;
            case 4:treeObj.setRownum((BigDecimal)arr[i]);break;
            }
        }
        list.add(treeObj);
    }
    model.addAttribute("treeViewList", list);
    return new ModelAndView("userHome");    

}
```

how to display that list in jsp as dynaTree

and List whic i got having values as level,title,titleId,parentId
and  value is suppose
level,title,titleId,parentId

1    India  1        0

2    MH     2        1

3    Mumbai  13       2

4    Dl     3        1

5   Noida   12       3

Comment: Have you tried something yet? Could you provide your non-working JSP code snippet?

Comment: i have simple jsp ,and i didnt get any idea to display that list as treeview,please give me idea